# How is it possible to findout duration of a video file form http response

Tags: video, http-headers, httpresponse, duration

When downloading a video file with IDM, sometimes it shows the duration of video instead of length in bytes. How is it possible? 
As I remember, there is no specific information (say video frame rate or length) about a particular file format (say a video file), in http response header.

Comment: IDM probably looks at the file header and extracts the file duration from it, same thing you can do with libraries such as [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). In most file formats, few hundred bytes of the file header will be enough to extract its duration.

Comment: you are right! How didn't I think of it! thank U